# How can i get specific column from csv file and put that items of column into jComboBox using java?

Tags: java, csv, user-interface, while-loop

part of my code is here:

```
private void toCombo()
    {
    
    String data="C:\\Users\\Berk\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Getränklist.csv";
    String line="";
   
    try
    { 
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(data));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {   
  
                String[] record=line.split(",");            
                System.out.println(record[1]); //i can get column here              
                DefaultComboBoxModel model=new DefaultComboBoxModel(record); // but here i cant get column bcz record[1] doesnt accepted by compiler.
//as a matter of fact only last line appears in ComboBox. 
                    cmb.setModel(model);
                }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

i am pretty novice in Java and can't do the thing that i want. for example i wanna get all items from 2. column and set them into ComboBox. I tried many things, searched many sites but failed.  If somebody can help me i'd be much appreciated.
here you can see my output:

```
England        Turkey         Germany        
India          China          Japan          
USA            Canada         Poland         
Holland        France         Spain          

Turkey
China
Canada
France
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JComboBox already have a ComboBoxModel. There is no need for you to create another one.

In your while loop all you need is:

```
comboBox.addItem( record[1] );
```

> I tried many things, searched many sites but failed

Start with the basics from the Swing tutorial. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more information.

Comment: omg that worked, i dont belive that that was so easy. thank you sir. understood